# "a few percent" or "a few percents"? Why?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

The sentences as follow:

"Problem is, the material Jing developed is six percent heavier than the standard stuff. And more weight means more fuel means more expense. But if we settled for a slightly quieter flight, Jing says he could use less latex, making the noise-blocking honeycomb **just a few percent(or a few percents?)** heavier."

My question is should I use "**a few percents**" in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

No. "A few percent" means a few per hundred (Latin:per centum), and it invariant as to number. If you want to emphasize individual steps of percent, you could say "a few percentage points".